# Linux user administrator hierarchy

Tags: linux, ubuntu, administrator, users, user-groups

Can I have two users, one above other, but all can run all sudo commands and run all sudo applications, except user below, is not allowed specific small group of actions,set by user above. Ideally, both are admins, but one is not allowed all actions. For example, both have same privileges, except user below is not allowed only to edit /etc/hosts file.

Comment: I think you should have two groups and change owner of `hosts` file so that only the allowed admin can edit that. Is that what you want?

Comment: If all sudo commands are allowed, the user can also remove any restrictions

Comment: To enlarge upon what @Virsacer said: there are dozens (maybe hundreds) of questions on this site about how to allow a user to do "anything and everything, except for X, Y and Z" in ``sudo``, and the answer almost always is that it's impossible. If you give a user broad administrative rights, they can break through and gain full power.